# EF Core Calculated Properties from Related Entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a Project that uses EF Core Code First on MSSQL.

I have these Entities saved to DB.

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    public CoverType CoverType { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public static Expression<Func<Author, int>> PagesOfLongestBook
    {
        get
        {
            return a =>
                a.Books.Select(b => b.Pages).OrderByDescending(b => b).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    public static Expression<Func<Author, bool>> HasHardCoveredBooks
    {
        get
        {
            return a =>
                a.Books.Exists(b => b.CoverType == CoverType.Hard);
        }
    }
}

public enum CoverType
{
    Hard = 1,
    Soft = 2
}
```

As you can guess, the Expressions are the interesting part, but to be complete, a few more configurations.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Author>(builder =>
    {
        builder.Navigation(a => a.Books).AutoInclude();
    }
    builder.Entity<Book>(builder =>
    {
        builder.Navigation(a => a.Author).AutoInclude();
    }
}
```

Entities are Mapped to ViewModels via AutoMapper configured as

```
public class AuthorProfile : Profile
{
    public AuthorProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Author, ViewModel>()
            .ForMember(vm => vm.PagesOfLongestBook, opt => opt.MapFrom(a => Author.PagesOfLongestBook.Compile().Invoke(a)));
    }
}
```

and finally, the query looks like

```
dbcontext.Authors.Skip(10).Take(10).ProjectTo(config, Array.Empty<Expression<Func<Author, object>>>());
```

you can imagine, that i skipped a few layers like permission handling, generic filter builder and so on, which seems unimportant to me at this point.

the dataset im working with is about 200k authors and 30mio books.

in the current state, loading could perform better (especially if an author with many books is in the results) but its not too bad.
if i remove one of the expression properties, loading time are really good.

filtering and sorting on the expression properties results in a timeout on the database side.

is there a better way to calculate properties across tables?

if there are code parts that you are missing, please let me know!

Comment: Try to add `AsSplitQuery()`, you have *autoincluded* a lot of eager loading records.

Comment: that made simple queries even faster and filtering is working on both properties. sorting is working on `HasHardCoveredBooks`, but not on `PagesOfLongestBook`. Thank you very much! I will try to further improve it by adding indexes on these columns.

Comment: I do not see filtering here, alt least small sample. Also why you have auto included entities? Because it crashes?

Comment: You can use `IncludeMembers` instead of those expressions and you can remove all eager loading, let `ProjectTo` do its thing.

Comment: But I'm not even sure you need `IncludeMembers`. Why not simply write that expression inside `MapFrom`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I made a Library for filtering, sorting, pagination, etc. Probably its too much to show it in this question, but you can check it out here https://github.com/timewarp-it/xtentityframework/blob/main/Example.Blazor/Server/Controllers/StudentsController.cs. It creates a LINQ Function based on a PropertyName, Comparison like == and a value. so you could treat it like `.Where(author => author.PagesOfLongestBook  > 100)`.
@LucianBargaoanu I wasnt aware of `IncludeMembers` tbh.  I will check it out in more detail, but it seems like i still have to include it, so `Books` isn't null

Comment: @MariusSteinbach, are you ok to use third party extension, like LINQKit? I'll show how to make such properties filterable.

Comment: No, you don't need `Include` with `ProjectTo`, the same you don't need it with any `Select`, what's in the DTO gets fetched automatically. But a simple `MapFrom` should do here.